# Is there a way to schedule two reports at the same hour?

Tags: reporting, scheduled

When I schedule a report to execute in a hour, for example 8:00 AM. I cannot schedule another report in this same hour.

I want to do it for two or more reports.

Comment: There is an AppExchange listing called [Conga Courier](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016ZopEAE) that will let you schedule additional reports for email delivery.

Comment: Or Conga Composer for more advanced output formats. Vendor offers first rate support, by phone no less (I've used Conga on multiple orgs)

Answer (score 1):

This is covered by SFDC limits: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_analytics_per_edition.htm&language=en_US. Varies by Edition